# Загрузка изображений в приложение Android

Tags: android

Подскажите как реализовать механизм загрузки изображений к примеру из галлереи в свое приложение и как с ними потом обращать в приложении. Хотя бы идейно подскажите, а дальше я подхвачу.

Comment: смотря какой функционал нужен. есть разные библиотеки, к примеру, Glide

Comment: нужно просто загружать картинки в приложение,  потом показывать их там

Comment: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader посмотрите библиотеку, там есть примеры, думаю сразу все поймете

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через интент:

Запустим `activity` с `Intent ACTION_PICK` для загрузки картинки из стандартной галереи Android, для этого создаем `Intent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
i.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST);
```

При создании Intent передаем константу `ACTION_PICK`, чтобы показать, что нам нужно выбрать какие-то `данные.i.setType("image/*")` – а здесь указываем тип данных, какой хотим получить.И реализуем метод `onActivityResult`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
     Bitmap img = null;
     if (requestCode == REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
          try {
               img = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

У нас есть `img` с которым уже работаем как с обычной `Bitmap`.

Comment: Ну и стиль кода (